# enter java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError in IDEA running glassfish 6.2.0

Tags: java, intellij-idea, server, glassfish

I'm using the IDEA to do some assignment about the JSF.
And I'm just running a simple project with glassfish, and the output is like this:

[the out put](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DdciX.png)

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/glassfish/admin/cli/AsadminMain has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
```

I searched on the google, and know that version 52 means jdk 8, so I delete all the other jdk, and only leave the jdk8, and the version is indeed 1.8:

[the java version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XvS0y.png)

```
C:\Users\42173>java -version
java version "1.8.0_291"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_291-b10)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.291-b10, mixed mode)

C:\Users\42173>javac -version
javac 1.8.0_291
```

But it still shows the same error, I don't know what to do.

And I have tried glassfish5, but the output still has error:

[exception with glassfish5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ujVD.png)

```
[2021-06-18 11:14:13,323] Artifact untitled1:war exploded: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
[2021-06-18 11:14:13,818] Artifact untitled1:war exploded: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
[2021-06-18 11:14:13,818] Artifact untitled1:war exploded: java.io.IOException: com.sun.enterprise.admin.remote.RemoteFailureException: Error occurred during deployment: Exception while deploying the app [untitled1_war_exploded] : A MultiException has 4 exceptions.  They are:
1. java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class sun.security.provider.SunEntries from class com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE
2. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: post construct on com.sun.enterprise.security.ssl.SSLUtils
3. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: While attempting to resolve the dependencies of com.sun.enterprise.security.SecurityLifecycle errors were found
4. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: resolve on com.sun.enterprise.security.SecurityLifecycle
. Please see server.log for more details.
```

Answer (score 0):

You got the error message wrong.

```
... has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0),
this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
```

It does not tell you that you need Java 8 but instead that Java 8 (class version `52`) is too old to run classes compiled by version `55` (i.e. Java 11).

So you need to install JDK 11.